# TSQL order by group for monthly reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have court clearance statistic to made, but i have some slight problem with my monthly.. it didt follow in order, and wish someone could help me fix it.. and is it possible to add total in my table?

```
DECLARE @StartDate As date = '03-28-2015',
@EndDate As date = '03-28-2015'



DECLARE @TEMP_DATES AS TABLE (FROM_DATE DATE, TO_DATE DATE)
INSERT INTO @TEMP_DATES VALUES(@StartDate, @EndDate)

DECLARE @TENP_MONTH_YEAR AS TABLE(MONTH_YEAR VARCHAR(20), [YEAR] INT, [MONTH] INT)
INSERT INTO @TENP_MONTH_YEAR
select FORMAT(D.Dates, 'MMMM-yy', 'en-US' ) AS MonthYear, YEAR(D.Dates), MONTH(D.Dates)
from @TEMP_DATES as T
  inner join master..spt_values as N
    on N.number between 0 and datediff(DAY, T.FROM_DATE, T.TO_DATE)
    cross apply (select dateadd(DAY, N.number, T.FROM_DATE)) as D(Dates)
where N.type ='P'
GROUP BY FORMAT(D.Dates, 'MMMM-yy', 'en-US' ), YEAR(D.Dates), MONTH(D.Dates)
ORDER BY YEAR(D.Dates), MONTH(D.Dates)

DECLARE @NEWID AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()

SELECT CT.RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP, SUM(ISNULL(INCOMING_CASES, 0)) AS INCOMING_CASES, SUM(ISNULL(OUTGOING_CASES, 0)) AS OUTGOING_CASES,
ISNULL(CAST(SUM(NULLIF(CAST(ISNULL(OUTGOING_CASES, 0) AS DECIMAL),0.00))/SUM(NULLIF(CAST(ISNULL(INCOMING_CASES, 0) AS DECIMAL),0.00)) * 100 AS DECIMAL(18,2)),0) AS [CLEARANCE_RATE], 
MONTH_YEAR
FROM @tempClearanceListCases tempCLC
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CASE_TYPE_ID, MONTH_YEAR, [YEAR], [MONTH]
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CASE_TYPE_ID FROM @tempClearanceListCases tempCLC ) A, @TENP_MONTH_YEAR tempMonthYear) B
    ON B.CASE_TYPE_ID = tempCLC.CASE_TYPE_ID AND tempCLC.MONTHLY = B.MONTH_YEAR
INNER JOIN CaseType CT WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON B.CASE_TYPE_ID = CT.CASE_TYPE_ID 
WHERE ISNULL(COURT_LOCATION_ID, @NEWID) = ISNULL(@COURT_LOCATION_ID, ISNULL(COURT_LOCATION_ID, @NEWID))
GROUP BY CT.RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP, [INTERVAL_MONTH], MONTH_YEAR
ORDER BY CT.RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP
```

The result which is the monthly is not correct order:

```
RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP | INCOMEING CASES | OUTGOING CASES | CLEARANCERATE |  MONTHYEAR

BCY/CP                    15               4                 26.67         March-15
BCY/CP                    15               0                 0.00          February-15
BCY/CP                    33               0                 0.00          January-15
BCY/DP                     0               0                 0.00          February-15
BCY/DP                     2               0                 0.00          March-15
BCY/DP                     1               0                 0.00          January-15
```

The result atleast i want it to be  :

```
RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP | INCOMEING CASES | OUTGOING CASES | CLEARANCERATE |  MONTHYEAR
BCY/CP                    33               0                 0.00          January-15
BCY/CP                    15               0                 0.00          February-15
BCY/CP                    15               4                 26.67         March-15
BCY/DP                     1               0                 0.00          January-15
BCY/DP                     0               0                 0.00          February-15
BCY/DP                     2               0                 0.00          March-15
```

The result i want :

```
RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP | INCOMEING CASES | OUTGOING CASES | CLEARANCERATE |  MONTHYEAR
BCY/CP                    33               0                 0.00          January-15
BCY/CP                    15               0                 0.00          February-15
BCY/CP                    15               4                 26.67         March-15
                          63               4                 6.34          Overall
BCY/DP                     1               0                 0.00          January-15
BCY/DP                     0               0                 0.00          February-15
BCY/DP                     2               0                 0.00          March-15
                           3               0                 0.00          Overall
```

DO i have to stick to my query or create grouping query? i already spend many hour on this, i feel hard to turn back, im fresh grad :( can any guru guide me?

Comment: I assume your issue is that you cannot accurately order by using the `MONTHYEAR` since it is text. Is this correct?

Comment: its not text, its a datename, i can order by MONTHYEAR but it will mess up my case code group.. @Nicarus

Comment: Why? Order by `RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP` first, then the `MONTHYEAR`

Comment: I already did that, but still it not following order @Nicarus

Comment: Because the order by is sorting on the textual representation of the `MONTHYEAR` - so, alphabetically. You can use a case statement in your `ORDER BY` to correct this. Of course, you could also just add a calculated "sort" field and `order by` on that

Comment: As listed in my answer below, query each `RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP` for the period (3 months in this case), then `UNION ALL` with a query of the same rccg using the `SUM(column_name)` aggregate function to get your `Overall` row. I just noticed the `CLEARANCERATE` column is an `AVERAGE(column_name)` rather than a `SUM(column_name)`, but it essentially works the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all your MONTHYEAR are following the sames patter monthname-xx you can use following statement on order:

```
 ORDER BY 
    cast('20' + substring(MONTHYEAR, Charindex('-', MONTHYEAR) + 1, 2) + '-' + substring(MONTHYEAR, 1, 3) + '-01' AS date)
```

Comment: @JohhnyNewbie, I changed the statement. Just let me know if this works for you. thank

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for the `UNION` clause. It seems like you should have this execution order for the results you want:

```
SELECT -- data you want from tables w/ all joins
WHERE RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP = 'BCY/CP'
UNION ALL
SELECT '', SUM([INCOMING CASES]), SUM([OUTGOING CASES]), AVG([CLEARANCE RATE], 'Overall'
FROM -- source data
WHERE RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP = 'BCY/CP'
UNION ALL
SELECT -- data you want from tables w/ all joins
WHERE RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP = 'BCY/DP'
UNION ALL
SELECT '', SUM([INCOMING CASES]), SUM([OUTGOING CASES]), AVG([CLEARANCE RATE], 'Overall'
FROM -- source data
WHERE RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP = 'BCY/CP'
```

Alternatively, if there are more `RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP` values than the one presented, you can use a loop to capture information about all of them like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #rccg(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP NVARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO #rccg(RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP)
SELECT DISTINCT RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP FROM --data source

DECLARE @i INT = 1, @j INT = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #rccg), @rccg NVARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @results TABLE(rccg NVARCHAR(15), ic INT, oc INT, cr INT, my NVARCHAR(20))
WHILE @i < @j
BEGIN
    SET @rccg = (SELECT RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP FROM #rccg WHERE ID = @i)
    INSERT INTO @results
    SELECT -- data you want from tables w/ all joins
    WHERE RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP = @rccg
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '', SUM([INCOMING CASES]), SUM([OUTGOING CASES]), AVG([CLEARANCE RATE], 'Overall'
    FROM -- source data
    WHERE RPT_CASE_CODE_GROUP = @rccg
END
SELECT * FROM @rccg
DROP TABLE #rccg
```

I know I didn't use your specific code, because that would have taken up a huge amount of space, but I think you get the general idea. For each field you want the totals of for the time period, you use the `SUM(column_name)` aggregate function. You can get a pretty good explanation and examples here: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php.

I hope this at least helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: alright i will try use this, but im afraid about the month.. anywhere can i contact u possible?

Comment: @JohhnyNewbie I'm on here most week days and Saturdays when I'm working.

Comment: this also correct answer for total.. er i cant mark 2 answer

Comment: there more easy way, just do order by with ROLLUP :D BAM!!